# Subarray with given sum and return lowest starting index

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

Given an unsorted array A of size N that contains only positive integers, find a continuous sub-array that adds to a given number S and return the left and right index(1-based indexing) of that subarray.

In case of multiple subarrays, return the subarray indexes which come first on moving from left to right.

Note:- You have to return an ArrayList consisting of two elements left and right. In case no such subarray exists return an array consisting of element -1.
example 1:
Input:
N = 5, S = 12
A[] = {1,2,3,7,5}
Output: 2 4
Explanation: The sum of elements
from 2nd position to 4th position
is 12.
example 2:
Input:
N = 10, S = 15
A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
Output: 1 5
Explanation: The sum of elements
from 1st position to 5th position
is 15

I just want the optimized code for this algorithm.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

def subArraySum(self,A, n, s):

```
    l=[]
 
    if s>sum(A):
        return [-1]
        
    for i in range(n):
        sum_num=A[i]
        if (sum_num==s):
            return [i+1,i+1]
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            sum_num+=A[j]
            if (sum_num==s):
                l.append([i+1,j+1])
                
            elif(sum_num>s):
               break
           
    if len(l)==0:
        return [-1]
   
    else:
        min=l[0][0]
        flag=0
    
        for i in l:
            if i[0]<min:
                min=i[0]
                flag=i
        if flag:
          
            return (l[0])
        else:
          
            return (l[flag])
```

Comment: If the codes works, you can probably try asking at [codereview.se].

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In addition to other comments, look here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions